# Add ID columns to (denormalized) Raw File Source

Tags: ssis

I have a Raw File Source that outputs this kind of dataset:

```
╔════════╦════════╦═════════════╗
║ Region ║  City  ║ Subdivision ║
╠════════╬════════╬═════════════╣
║ R5     ║ City A ║ Q1          ║
║ R5     ║ City A ║ Q2          ║
║ R5     ║ City A ║ Q3          ║
║ R9     ║ City X ║ Q1          ║
║ R9     ║ City Y ║ Q1          ║
║ R9     ║ City B ║ Q1          ║
║ R9     ║ City B ║ Q2          ║
╚════════╩════════╩═════════════╝
```

I would like to add ID column to each existing column, in order to get this kind of dataset:

```
╔══════════╦════════╦════════╦════════╦═══════╦═════════════╗
║ RegionID ║ Region ║ CityID ║  City  ║ SubID ║ Subdivision ║
╠══════════╬════════╬════════╬════════╬═══════╬═════════════╣
║        1 ║ R5     ║      1 ║ City A ║     1 ║ Q1          ║
║        1 ║ R5     ║      1 ║ City A ║     2 ║ Q2          ║
║        1 ║ R5     ║      1 ║ City A ║     3 ║ Q3          ║
║        2 ║ R9     ║      2 ║ City X ║     4 ║ Q1          ║
║        2 ║ R9     ║      3 ║ City Y ║     5 ║ Q1          ║
║        2 ║ R9     ║      4 ║ City B ║     6 ║ Q1          ║
║        2 ║ R9     ║      4 ║ City B ║     7 ║ Q2          ║
╚══════════╩════════╩════════╩════════╩═══════╩═════════════╝
```

Until now, I found the way to do it using SQL Server database, but I would really like to avoid that intermediate step.
Can this be done in SSIS?

**EDIT**

I have to be clear enough about creating identifiers using database (e.g. *IDENTITY* column).

First, that means that I have to persist data to the database at the time I want the identifiers. I want to have identifiers BEFORE I have to write to the database - data shouldn't be written to the database until the final step is reached. Why? Because in that final step I will have quite a few (raw) file sources - few of them are quite *BIG* - that I will have to verify one against the another and perform some corrections. If they are in database and not raw files some will have to be updated. Updating 1M rows in SSIS is *REALLY SLOW*. Imagine doing that several times in one package.

Even if I use database tables instead of raw file sources for intermediate results, it means that I'm writing temporary data to database to multiple structures which I have to manually create. In my example this sums up 3 tables, but this is not my only data source. Think ~20 sources, something like 2-5 tables per source. It means creating 40-100 temporary table structures. I really DON'T want to do that.

Comment: Is this a one time event or a process that you will need to repeat in the future? What I mean is, will you need to remember in the future that RegionID "1" was assigned to Region "R5" and then always assign that RegionID to that Region? Do you need RegionID to be a persistent Primary Key across multiple outputs?

Answer (score 0):

It is technically feasible to generate an incrementing sequential number and inject this into a data flow in SSIS. These articles show you how:

[SSIS generating row numbers](http://www.jasonstrate.com/2011/01/31-days-of-ssis-generating-row-numbers-2331/)

[How to Generate an Auto Incremental Number in a SSIS Package](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/2008/ssis-auto-increment/)

However, given this requirement, don't do it:

**The ID must be a primary key that is persistent across multiple outputs and multiple cyles**

For your convenicence and sanity, I would always track those IDs in tables that look something like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.Region( 
     RegionId int IDENTITY(1 , 1) NOT NULL
    ,Region varchar(10) NOT NULL
    ,ActiveIndicator int NOT NULL DEFAULT 1
    ,LoadDateTime datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT GETDATE( )
CONSTRAINT PK_Region PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED( Region ASC ));

CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Region_Candidate_Key] ON [dbo].[Region] 
([RegionId] ASC)
INCLUDE ( [Region],[ActiveIndicator]);
```

A table in SQL Server gives you quite a few features with little effort:

- Enforce data integrity by creating a primary key
- Leverage the `IDENTITY` property to create a unique sequence
- Keep track of inactive Regions (ActiveIndicator = 0)
- Keep track of Load date and time for each Region

I guess you could do the same in a flat file outside a database, but it would be quite a bit more work on your end and ever so much easier to get out of sync.

Keep it in a table in a database and you can always know your source of truth.

What compelling reasons would you have not to put the data in a database?

If one is cost, then it does not have to be SQL Server. SSIS can connect to a number of RDBMSs (including MySQL or even MS Access).

Comment: Please see edited question - I explained why I really don't want identifiers to be created by the database. Of course that *at the end* results will be persisted. Destination is SQL Server database.